# How does Dir function in VBA remembers last used path?

Tags: vba

In VBA, When I use Dir function first with a path as argument, then later without any argument, it returns the name of next file in the path. It stores the last used path even after the execution of that function is complete. As far as I know, to 'remember' something in a normal function, we need to use a global variable. How does Dir function remember it. I think I am missing some concept in VBA here.

Comment: You're not missing anything, that's just how the Dir function works. Dir is a bit of an oddball function. It has been around since the original BASIC language and several of those older functions look a bit inconsistent (see also: Open & Close, Line Input, etc.). Another way to implement the same functionality might have been to split the function into two separate functions, maybe call Dir with an argument BeginDir and Dir without an argument ContinueDir.

Comment: That's an internal mechanism of the Dir-function.  If you think about it, it not only needs to remember the path, it also needs to remember which file was already returned. Only thing you need to worry about is that you don't issue another Dir-command with parameter when you're not done with looping all files.

Comment: Related function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chdir-statement

Comment: @NicholasHunter: Exactly this is done under the hood, using `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`, using a `WIN32_FIND_DATAA` data structure

Comment: @braX You are linking to the `ChDir`-function - probably you ment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function

Comment: No, i meant the related `ChDir` function

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are the missing link to the puzzle.  Although, there may very well be something else going on, `Dir()` behaves like it has a static variable that holds the last call to the function.  It will hold this information until the execution environment is stopped or reset.

Here is a simple a simple example of a static variable:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To 10
        Debug.Print Counter
    Next
End Sub

Function Counter()
    Static count As Long
    count = count + 1
    Counter = count
End Function
```

Comment: The function can be also made static and then all local variables are treated as static.

Comment: Note to OP: `Dir`'s actual implementation is not VBA (i.e. the VBE7.DLL is not written in VBA)... so this answer could be thought of as a demonstration/simplification in VBA of what is [actually happening under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67004104/how-does-dir-function-in-vba-remembers-last-used-path#comment118437795_67004104).

Comment: @KostasK. I should have mentioned that in my post.  In truth, my answer wasn't very good.

Comment: @BigBen Great point and a better answer than my own.

Comment: Side note, "Static" in VBA means something radically different than what you might find about "static" in other languages. The VB-esque equivalent of other-languages `static` is the concept of a `Shared` declaration. The implications of the `Static` modifier at member level are not widely known, and rather bug-prone; knowing what `Static` does at member level is very good, using it.. not so much IMO ;-)